# print something in the middle of while loop when it breaks

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I want the program to understand if the list given is consecutive or not and I'm using this code but my problem is that I don't know where to put `print("Consecutive")` to get one time consecutive in the console

```
def solution(A):
    sorted_list = sorted(A)
    minimum = min(A)
    for i in range(len(A)):
        while minimum in sorted_list:
            minimum += 1
            break
        else:
            print("Not Consecutive")
            break


solution([4, 1, 3, 2])
```

Comment: The `break` in the `while` loop makes no sense. It will immediately make the `while` loop stop, so you can just leave the loop away all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that you can do is `return` after the you print `Not Consecutive` instead of `break` and print `consecutive` at the end of the function. Thus, if the condition is not satisfied, the program will exit the function and the line `print("Consecutive")` won't get executed.

```
def solution(A):
    sorted_list = sorted(A)
    minimum = min(A)
    for i in range(len(A)):
        while minimum in sorted_list:
            minimum += 1
            break
        else:
            print("Not Consecutive")
            return
    print("Consecutive")

solution([4, 1, 3, 2])
# Consecutive
```

Comment: @iman_sh77, this program is not at all efficient. This can be achieved in `O(n)` time complexity. I suggest you to try and come up with a new solution.

Comment: I will be glad if you tell me your opinion how can I reach my solution in 0(n) time. thanks

Comment: The fastest solution would be this: Find the min, max, and length of list in a single loop. `if max-min+1 <= length` it's consecutive. Won't be a Pythonic solution though.